# Cancel automatic Countdown timer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a CountDownTimer. I want it to stop when I give an answer. If I press a button (ant1 or ant2) it opens a new XML without stopping the timer. This is my code:

```java
public class Vraag1 extends Activity {
    TextView text1;

    private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";

    int seconds , minutes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vraag1);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { 

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                text1.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Intent c = new Intent(Vraag1.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(c);
            }
        }.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent a = new Intent(Vraag1.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.Ant1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Vraag1.this, Vraag1Fout.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Ant2) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Vraag1.this, Vraag1Fout.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Ant3) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Vraag1.this, Vraag1Goed.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Ant4) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Vraag1.this, Vraag1Fout.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a CountDownTimer. I want it to stop when I give an answer

to stop it, you have to call `cancel();` on the `CountDownTimer` instance, when you press the button. If you keep

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer
```

as class member, and assign correctly `countDownTimer`, in your onCreate, then you can use it to call `cancel()` when `onClick` is invoked. This will cancel the `CountDownTimer`

Comment: Can you give me an example . im just a beginner.